# Referencing a ASP:TextBox control - run time error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a file called Play.aspx with these controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGuess" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit Guess" OnClick="PostGuess" />
```

The Sub "PostGuess" is in the CodeFile (Play.aspx.vb) and a line in this Sub references the TextBox using txtGuess.Text

I also have this line in Play.aspx.vb:

```
Protected WithEvents txtGuess As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
```

This is the contents of my Play.aspx.designer.vb file:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Partial Public Class Play
Protected WithEvents Head1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead
Protected WithEvents form1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
Protected WithEvents ScriptManager1 As Global.System.Web.UI.ScriptManager
Protected WithEvents LoginView1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView
```

When I run the web app, I put some text in txtGuess and click Button1 and it gives me this error on the txtGuess.Text:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Issued has been FIXED

The problem was the textbox was inside a ASP:LoginView control